# How do I remove a manifest from a precompiled dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, manifest

I have a precompiled c++ dll that I need to remove or replace the embedded manifest from.  Is there a way that I can do this from the command line?  I know it is possible to open the dll in VS and simply delete the manifest, but I would like to automate this process if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems the standard tool to deal with manifests mt.exe shipped with VS cannot delete them. But if you are familiar with c++ it's quite easy to write your own tool for this purpose.

You just need to call [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with given dll name, then [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with lpData = NULL and cbData = 0 to delete given resource type (RT_MANIFEST) and EndUpdateResource to commit changes.

Comment: Thanks, What to pass against lpName? Getting return 0 from update call with below: HANDLE hUpdate = BeginUpdateResourceA(pathToDll.c_str(), false); bool success = UpdateResourceA(hUpdate, RT_MANIFEST, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(1), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),NULL, 0);

Comment: I am using a .NET C# DLL

Comment: addition: if UpdateResource() failed and GetLastError() return 87 'The parameter is incorrect', try to ensure 'wLanguage' is same as the resource in dll/exe. (Using VS->Open(xx.DLL)->Properties->Language, 0x0409 for en-US)