# Can I remove manifest of a pre-compiled .NET C# dll using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, dll, manifest

Can I remove the `Manifest` of a precompiled .NET DLL and use the remaining content to generate a hash of the DLL using powershell? The version differs in the DLLs even though no difference in code - I want to generate same hash for cases where only the `Manifest` is updated.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037848/how-do-i-remove-a-manifest-from-a-precompiled-dll/26040313

Comment: Thanks, What to pass against lpName? Getting return 0 from update call with below:
`HANDLE hUpdate = BeginUpdateResourceA(pathToDll.c_str(), false);
 bool success = UpdateResourceA(hUpdate, RT_MANIFEST, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(1), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),NULL, 0);`

Comment: I am using a .NET C# DLL